# Why this iteration is random?

Tags: arrays, swift

### Description

So my intention is to iterate this 'map' and let it print each pair sequentially, however, I got the pairs randomly.

### Code & Output :

#### code

```
let map: [Int : String] =
    [1000 : "M", 900 : "CM", 500 : "D", 400 : "CD", 100 : "C", 90 : "XC", 50 : "L", 40 : "XL", 10 : "X", 9 : "IX", 5 : "V", 4 : "IV", 1 : "I"]

for pair in map {
    print(pair)
}
```

#### one of the outputs that Xcode gave :

```
(key: 10, value: "X")
(key: 50, value: "L")
(key: 5, value: "V")
(key: 4, value: "IV")
(key: 900, value: "CM")
(key: 500, value: "D")
(key: 1, value: "I")
(key: 1000, value: "M")
(key: 90, value: "XC")
(key: 9, value: "IX")
(key: 400, value: "CD")
(key: 40, value: "XL")
(key: 100, value: "C")
```

#### my desired output :

```
(key: 1000, value: "M")
(key: 900, value: "CM")
(key: 500, value: "D")
(key: 400, value: "CD")
(key: 100, value: "C")
(key: 90, value: "XC")
(key: 50, value: "L")
(key: 40, value: "XL")
(key: 10, value: "X")
(key: 9, value: "IX")
(key: 5, value: "V")
(key: 4, value: "IV")
(key: 1, value: "I")
```

Comment: for your  desire output you need to take a dictionary array like this `let map: [[Int : String]] = [[1000 : "M"], [900 : "CM"], [500 : "D"], [400 : "CD"], [100 : "C"], [90 : "XC"], [50 : "L"], [40 : "XL"], [10 : "X"], [9 : "IX"], [5 : "V"], [4 : "IV"], [1 : "I"]]` because dictionary does not conform key value order.

Comment: @RB's An array of dictionaries is not the ideal solution. It would be better to use an array of tuples, e.g. `[(key: Int, value: String)]`. Also, there is always the option to sort the values before usage.

Comment: yes I did this, thank you

Comment: @Sulthan yeah i agree with you. i give him quicker one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary):

> The order of key-value pairs in a dictionary is stable between mutations but is otherwise unpredictable. If you need an ordered collection of key-value pairs and don’t need the fast key lookup that Dictionary provides, see the KeyValuePairs type for an alternative.